# Touchpad is recognized but not working on Toshiba P855-S5312 - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, synaptics

i just made a new fresh install of ubuntu 12.10, everything works nice but the touchpad istn working, it is recognized but it is not working, here a [paste bin of what i get when I type "xinput list"](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1357219/).

```
$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Optical Mouse                      id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue with HP ProBook 4540s

the `xinput list` results:

```
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam [Fixed]                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys
```

Comment: Hey, are you running 12.10 on 64 bits too? maybe its something with the 64 bits version, for some reason on ubuntu's download webpage they still recommend the 32 bits..., im strongly thinking on changing to a 32 bits version...

Comment: Solved, i dont know how, but suddenly my touchpad its working, maybe something i installed or i dont know how, 2 days ago wasnt working but know after making a playonlinux installation it started working, i also installed a windows xp virtualbox machine, maybe it was that, well thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Nope I am using 32bit and still having problem yet after updating latest kernels.

Comment: Ok amigo, i dont know how but mine its working now, maybe you gotta wait for the next update or so, good luck!

Comment: Do not remember exactly how, but it worked later.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, i dont know how, but suddenly my touchpad its working, maybe something i installed or i dont know how, 2 days ago wasnt working but know after making a playonlinux installation it started working, i also installed a windows xp virtualbox machine, maybe it was that, well thanks anyway for your help.